# Integrating Webrtc Into a c++ Project on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, webrtc

Lately i managed to develop on Linux (Kubuntu) a simple Webrtc Streamer using the Webrtc C++ sdk.

I wanted to integrate my code to a project that i allready had under Windows Visual Studio 2015 in C++ too.

The problem is that i have a very hard time linking Webrtc through Cmake for my Project under Visual Studio 2015 (Community), i'am trying for weeks now. 
Is there a protocol(or anything else) to follow to be sure to integrate it smoothly through cmake ?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar to what you are trying to do by creating a new target in the WebRTC framework which built a DLL exporting some functions I wrote to interface with the WebRTC framework.

In my case, I did this by exporting C functions from the DLL, but you could also use COM to do the same thing. If you're trying to make it cross platform, exporting C functions from shared libraries is probably the best approach.

The benefit of this method is it provides a clean separation between the WebRTC framework, which requires the [GN](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/tools/gn/docs/quick_start.md) build tool and your own projects using cmake.

However, you will have to add your own new DLL target to the WebRTC framework GN files.